# SharePoint 2013 Workflow doesn't start after AAM modification

Tags: workflow

After modifying alternative access mapping, my workflows don't start.
Actually they got stuck at first stage.
I have SharePoint 2013 latest updates, and Workflow Manager.

Comment: Found any solution yet?